# Export Vnet | Subnet

Tags: azure, powershell, report

I'd like to export something like the view of the subnets that exist in a VNET like is displayed in the portal. Unfortunately there isn't an option to export this to a CSV. I have found powershell scripts online that can export subnet route tables and the associated subnets. I have also found powershell scripts to export details on vnets subnets. However I haven't been able to find scripts that combine both

[Script for Route tables by Aman Sharma](https://github.com/HarvestingClouds/PowerShellSamples/blob/master/Scripts/User%20Defined%20Routes%20(UDRs)%20or%20Route%20Tables%20Related%20Scripts/Report-UDRsWithSubnetInfo.ps1)

Ignore the synopsis and description I think he left them in from previous scripts

So I'm trying to reverse the logic i.e. get the subnet details and add the route tables for each subnet if it exists. However I'm not sure what I'm doing at this point! the script is erroring with:

```
Line |
  47 |  …         $routeTables = Get-AzRouteTable -Name $routeTableName -Resour …
     |                                                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Name'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command again.
```

The script ends and the CSV has everything but the route table details. So if you could help a noob I'd be very grateful here is what I have:

```
$PathToOutputCSVReport = "/path/output.csv"

$subs = Get-AzSubscription

#Checking if the subscriptions are found or not
if(($subs -ne $null) -or ($subs.Count -gt 0))
{
    #Creating Output Object
    $results = @()

    #Iterating over various subscriptions
    foreach($sub in $subs)
    {
        $SubscriptionId = $sub.SubscriptionId
        Write-Output $SubscriptionName

        #Selecting the Azure Subscription
        Select-AzSubscription -SubscriptionName $SubscriptionId

        #Getting all Azure Route Tables
        $vnets = Get-AzVirtualNetwork

        foreach($vnet in $vnets)
        {
            $vnetName = $vnet.Name
            $vnetResourceGroup = $vnet.ResourceGroupName
            Write-Output $vnetName

            #Fetch Route Subnets
            $vnetSubnets = $vnet.Subnets

            foreach($vnetSubnet in $vnetSubnets)
            {
                $subnetName = $vnetSubnet.Name
                Write-Output $subnetName

                $subnetId = $vnetSubnet.Id

                ###Getting information
                $splitarray = $subnetId.Split('/')
                $subscriptionId = $splitarray[2]
                $vNetResourceGroupName = $splitarray[4]
                $virtualNetworkName = $splitarray[8]
                $subnetName = $splitarray[10]

                #Fetch the route table details
                $routeTables = Get-AzRouteTable -Name $routeTableName -ResourceGroupName $routeResourceGroup

                #Fetching the vNet and Subnet details
                #$vnet = Get-AzVirtualNetwork -Name $virtualNetworkName -ResourceGroupName $vNetResourceGroupName
                $subnet = Get-AzVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig -Name $subnetName -VirtualNetwork $vnet
        
                $subnetAddressPrefix = $subnet.AddressPrefix[0]

                $details = @{            
                        virtualNetworkName=$virtualNetworkName
                        subnetAddressPrefix=$subnetAddressPrefix
                        subnetName=$subnetName
                        routeTableName=$routeTableName
                        routeResourceGroup=$routeResourceGroup
                        subscriptionId=$subscriptionId
                        vNetResourceGroupName=$vNetResourceGroupName
                        
                }                           
                $results += New-Object PSObject -Property $details
                

            }

        }
    }
    $results | export-csv -Path $PathToOutputCSVReport -NoTypeInformation
}
else
{
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red "No Subscription Found"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error you're getting clearly shows that the variable `routeTableName` is an invalid value for the `-Name` parameter of the cmdlet `Get-AzRouteTable`.

Looking at your script, it appears that the variable is not defined anywhere, which explains why its empty, hence invalid to be used with the cmdlet.

To define the variable with the name of the route table associated to a subnet, you can use the following:

```
$routeTableName = $subnet.RouteTable.Id.Split('/')[8]
```

It also seems you're not using the following at all and can be removed:

```
$routeTables = Get-AzRouteTable -Name $routeTableName -ResourceGroupName $routeResourceGroup
```

Here's how your entire code would look like:

```
$PathToOutputCSVReport = "/path/output.csv"

$subs = Get-AzSubscription

#Checking if the subscriptions are found or not
if(($subs -ne $null) -or ($subs.Count -gt 0))
{
    #Creating Output Object
    $results = @()

    #Iterating over various subscriptions
    foreach($sub in $subs)
    {
        $SubscriptionId = $sub.SubscriptionId
        Write-Output $SubscriptionName

        #Selecting the Azure Subscription
        Select-AzSubscription -SubscriptionName $SubscriptionId

        #Getting all Azure Route Tables
        $vnets = Get-AzVirtualNetwork

        foreach($vnet in $vnets)
        {
            $vnetName = $vnet.Name
            $vnetResourceGroup = $vnet.ResourceGroupName
            Write-Output $vnetName

            #Fetch Route Subnets
            $vnetSubnets = $vnet.Subnets

            foreach($vnetSubnet in $vnetSubnets)
            {
                $subnetName = $vnetSubnet.Name
                Write-Output $subnetName

                $subnetId = $vnetSubnet.Id

                ###Getting information
                $splitarray = $subnetId.Split('/')
                $subscriptionId = $splitarray[2]
                $vNetResourceGroupName = $splitarray[4]
                $virtualNetworkName = $splitarray[8]
                $subnetName = $splitarray[10]

                #Fetch the route table details
                #$routeTables = Get-AzRouteTable -Name $routeTableName -ResourceGroupName $routeResourceGroup

                #Fetching the vNet and Subnet details
                #$vnet = Get-AzVirtualNetwork -Name $virtualNetworkName -ResourceGroupName $vNetResourceGroupName
                $subnet = Get-AzVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig -Name $subnetName -VirtualNetwork $vnet
                $routeTableName = $subnet.RouteTable.Id.Split('/')[8]
        
                $subnetAddressPrefix = $subnet.AddressPrefix[0]

                $details = @{            
                        virtualNetworkName=$virtualNetworkName
                        subnetAddressPrefix=$subnetAddressPrefix
                        subnetName=$subnetName
                        routeTableName=$routeTableName
                        routeResourceGroup=$routeResourceGroup
                        subscriptionId=$subscriptionId
                        vNetResourceGroupName=$vNetResourceGroupName
                        
                }                           
                $results += New-Object PSObject -Property $details
                

            }

        }
    }
    $results | export-csv -Path $PathToOutputCSVReport -NoTypeInformation
}
else
{
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red "No Subscription Found"
}
```

Comment: This is great Ked, Thank you very much. The script errors for every subnet that doesn't have a route table but that really doesn't matter as it leaves the field blank in the CSV which is accurate. I was using the Get-AzRouteTables line as I was trying to get the name of the resource group for the route table

Comment: Cool, glad this helped. You could catch that error so as to let the script run nicely. I'll try to see if I can work on that and update it later. Please mark as answer or upvote accordingly :)

Answer (score 0):

We have tried the same and getting the same warning as yours ,

[image]

Looking at your script ,you are doing correct but have not provided any variable to read the `$routeTableName` or `$routeResourceGroup` at line 47. We have used foreach loop again to retrieve route table details as subnet and vnets you have used, Followed by the below script we are able to run it without any failures:-

```
$PathToOutputCSVReport = "/mylocalpath/output.csv"

$subs = Get-AzSubscription

#Checking if the subscriptions are found or not
if(($subs -ne $null) -or ($subs.Count -gt 0))
{
    #Creating Output Object
    $results = @()

    #Iterating over various subscriptions
    foreach($sub in $subs)
    {
        $SubscriptionId = $sub.SubscriptionId
        Write-Output $SubscriptionName

        #Selecting the Azure Subscription
        Select-AzSubscription -SubscriptionName $SubscriptionId

        #Getting all Azure Route Tables
        $vnets = Get-AzVirtualNetwork

        foreach($vnet in $vnets)
        {
            $vnetName = $vnet.Name
            $vnetResourceGroup = $vnet.ResourceGroupName
            Write-Output $vnetName

            #Fetch Route Subnets
            $vnetSubnets = $vnet.Subnets

            foreach($vnetSubnet in $vnetSubnets)
            {
                $subnetName = $vnetSubnet.Name
                Write-Output $subnetName

                $subnetId = $vnetSubnet.Id

                ###Getting information
                $splitarray = $subnetId.Split('/')
                $subscriptionId = $splitarray[2]
                $vNetResourceGroupName = $splitarray[4]
                $virtualNetworkName = $splitarray[8]
                $subnetName = $splitarray[10]

                #Fetch the route table details
                #$routeTables = Get-AzRouteTable -ResourceGroupName $routeResourceGroup -Name $routeTableName instead of this tried below line to fetch the route table details
                
        $routeTables = Get-AzRouteTable

        foreach($routeTable in $routeTables)
        {
            $routeTableName = $routeTable.Name
            $routeResourceGroup = $routeTable.ResourceGroupName
            Write-Output $routeName 

                #Fetching the vNet and Subnet details
                #$vnet = Get-AzVirtualNetwork -Name $virtualNetworkName -ResourceGroupName $vNetResourceGroupName
                $subnet = Get-AzVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig -Name $subnetName -VirtualNetwork $vnet
        
                $subnetAddressPrefix = $subnet.AddressPrefix[0]

                $details = @{            
                        virtualNetworkName=$virtualNetworkName
                        subnetAddressPrefix=$subnetAddressPrefix
                        subnetName=$subnetName
                        routeTableName=$routeTableName
                        routeResourceGroup=$routeResourceGroup
                        subscriptionId=$subscriptionId
                        vNetResourceGroupName=$vNetResourceGroupName
                        
                }                           
                $results += New-Object PSObject -Property $details
                
               }
            }

        }
    }
    $results | export-csv -Path $PathToOutputCSVReport -NoTypeInformation
}
else
{
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red "No Subscription Found"
}
```

***Also the link which  you have shared it will also list as per your requirement .***

[image]
***OUTPUT DETAILS FOR REFERENCE:-***

[image]

***CSV FILE :-***

[image]

*For more information to fetch the route details in different way as well please refer the below links:-*

- [***SO THREAD|Route Table Details***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68220607/route-table-details)  ,[***Output of Azure subnets with links to attached VNet, route table and NSG***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65424684/output-of-azure-subnets-with-links-to-attached-vnet-route-table-and-nsg)

Comment: Sorry Ajay I have looked at the results a little closer and running this script returns every route table for every subnet. I want it to return each subnet and return the specific route table that is associated to that subnet.  But it's progress so that's good - thanks for your help

Comment: In the last screenshot that shared in answer it returns me after sometime the result every subnets and route tables which are associate with each other.

Comment: I was trying to fix the issue from your script the error you are getting , Once the script run complete it will download csv file and saved on our local from there we can check all the details more clearly. Does your csv file downloaded..?

Comment: Hello @john,May i know if you have downloaded the csv file and if you are getting the desired results. Thanks .